# Set Input Variable at the Start of a Python Script

Tags: python

I'm working on a python script in Red Hat that connect to a SQL database and run queries on a specific row. What I am attempting to do is to set the row that I want to query as an input variable that get's passed into the script when i start it. For example, when I start the script I would like to just run the command:

```
./SQLQuery.py Row_To_Query = Row_Name
```

For a similar script that I have in VBScript I would run the wscript command like this:

```
wscript SQLQuery.vbs /name:Row_Name
```

Then the row name would get passed into the script and  the relevant data used as the script progresses.

My end goal is to run the python script as a task every 10 minuets or so and pull the relevant data from a specific row, but also have the ability to specify which row the SQL queries are run against without having to edit the script each time I want to run it.

Comment: Do you know about `sys.argv`?

Comment: How long is the average minuet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) to parse the commandline arguments given in a standard unix-like format:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--row-to-query', type=str, help='row to query')
namespace = parser.parse_args()

row_name = namespace.row_to_query
...
```

You'd then run the program like:

```
./SQLQuery.py --row-to-query=some_row_name
```

or

```
./SQLQuery.py --row-to-query some_row_name
```

both invocations should be equivalent.

Comment: +1 If it's a required argument, then `add_argument('row-to-query', ...)` lets you run the script simply as `./SQLQuery.py some_row_name`.